# WordPress add doble slash in URL

Tags: wordpress, url, icons

I'm Dev. WordPress site but this added // into URL.

[image]

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: not, found there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method-1 | wp-config.php

Add these two lines to your `wp-config.php`, where **"example.com"** is the correct location of your site.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

---

### Method-2 | functions.php

Add these two lines to your `functions.php`.

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

> **Note:** Both settings should include the `http://` part and should not have a slash `"/"` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Check your configurations in WP Backend Settings->General, or maybe you've defined a path somewhere in your wp-config file

**Edited**

try adding **define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://your-url.com/');** in wp-config

if your using an apache try to add an .htaccess configuration

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)?/?([0-9]+)?/?$ /index.php?p=$1&page=$2 [QSA]
```

refer to this article [link](http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/how-to-fix-bug-with-wordpress-domain-extra-trailing-slash-double-wordpress-trailing-slash/)

Comment: isn't there prntscr.com/fbc5ht and the wp-config.php is empty prntscr.com/fbc5qe

Comment: if your using apache try looking on your .htaccess refer to this article also http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/how-to-fix-bug-with-wordpress-domain-extra-trailing-slash-double-wordpress-trailing-slash/

Answer (score 0):

check base url in wordpress config, remove slash after base url

eg. base_url/ change to base_url

Comment: isn't there http://prntscr.com/fbc5ht  and the wp-config.php is empty  http://prntscr.com/fbc5qe

Comment: Check in your database

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fbcb3m but, a the moment my Site goes down for try to define('WP_SITEURL', 'your-url.com/'); in wp-config

Comment: Add it in that setting make the url crash so be down, try checking url to load css

Answer (score 0):

The list of things to check:

- site url in settings
- WP_SITEURL in wp-config
- .htaccess (backup and delete to check if it worked)
- change a theme for a moment - maybe this is the reason
- deactivate all plugins - if double slashes will be removed try activating them one by one until you'll find which causes the
  problems
- install your site on WAMP/MAMP/LAMP - check if the problem still exists